# Replacing only text portion

Tags: jquery

How can I replace only the text portion `Regret/Rlwl1` here leaving `input` element as it is:

```
<td id="td1" style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"><input type="RADIO" name="lccp_class4" value="3A">
Regret/Rlwl1</td>
```

Comment: `$('#td1').text("")`

Comment: @Alex it will remove the input element also

Comment: are you sure it will?

Comment: @user5858 Check my solution. There could be better ways.

Comment: Ah, found the better ways. `:)`

Comment: Er... This looks like our IRCTC? Is it so?

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes indeed

Comment: @user5858 Ha ha ha... Wild guess... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own way, but there are better ways.

```js
$(function () {
  $("#test").contents().each(function () {
    if (this.textContent.trim().length > 0)
      $(this).replaceWith('Hello');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <input type="RADIO" name="lccp_class4" value="3A">
  Regret/Rlwl1
</div>
```

**Update**

For those who cannot see the output for whatever reason, I get this:

[image]

**Better Version:**

```
$(selector).contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
})
.replaceWith(something_else);
```

**Working Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $("#test").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
  })
  .replaceWith("Hello");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"><input type="RADIO" name="lccp_class4" value="3A">Regret/Rlwl1</div>
```

Comment: OP want to remove the text from the td.... :P

Comment: @BhojendraNepal `can I replace only`: `replace != remove`.

Comment: Read `How can I replace only the text portion Regret/Rlwl1 here leaving input element as it is:`

Comment: Yea, I saw. Replace the `Regret/Rlw11` with `hello` and do not touch the input right? Gosh, understand English man.

Comment: It happens to use understand clearly with sometimes english.

Comment: I can't see `hello`?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal That's strange. I am getting this: http://i.imgur.com/MrQ9PDA.png

Comment: @BhojendraNepal See updated answer.

Comment: Its weird that I can't see really.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I understand. Which browser?

Comment: May be some problem with SO? I can't see anything after `I get this:` in your answer.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Stupid proxies. :P Man, I have used an image. Is imgur.com working for you?

Comment: You posted in the comment, I can see. but not either in question or answer.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Works fine on Firefox on Mac too. :)

Comment: don't what's happening.... may be some netwrok problem?

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Comment: anyway getting late. going home.... bye!

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Bye.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Check out. :)

Comment: ^1 for updated answer.